# How to get rid of left rounded corners in landscape mode on Android on some devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, layout, rounded-corners

In my app I would like to have no rounded corners in landscape mode. I don't want to use the notch area (on the left).
I use AppCompactActivity with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme.

XML layout is very simple: only ConstraintLayout with background.

On some devices I have round left corners. E.g. Samsung A21s - Android 12 rounded corners appear in landscape mode (notch area is black on the left side):
[image]

On Pixel 4 emulator there are no corners:
[image]

Is it a simple way to get rid of round corners on all devices?
I need it because I use Unity as a library in my app and Unity screens don't have round corners, but when I show android actitivy it has round corners on some devices. It doesn't look good. I try to use SurficeView as a background with some success but I think it is not a good idea (too many drawbacks).

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that, these devices are physically designed with that corner

Comment: More information: there are no rounded corners in portrait mode with the same layout. Layout is very simple, only ConstarintLayout with background. I try to use SurfaceView as a background with some success, but there were some black pixels in the corner.

Comment: It looks like the Pixel 4 just cuts off the extra space. Could you just add an all-black view at the top of the screen to accomplish the same thing?